# Extracting Datafram columns using regular expression from a big text file using python or R

Tags: python, r, regex, dataframe

I want to extract all the columns starting from line 1472  named "Physics", "Time", "dt",   "Progress", "Nonlinear Iteration"   "Linear Iterations"...."Nodes After Adaption") from the attached text file as a dataframe either in python or in R. I don't know how to use regular expression for that. I highly appreciate any help.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/30lkp.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvjiJ.png)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sLa5EjgbKNXf0u59PQNTkE_rMpMK8WN0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Read up on SO's notions of a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I used readLines, which does not have a skip parameter, I just read in the whole thing and then removed the first 1471 lines:

```
dat <- readLines("~/Documents/R_code/AR_20base_201214_adh.out" )
dat <- dat[-(1:1471)]
dat[1]
#[1] "Physics\tTime\tdt\tProgress\tNonlinear Iteration\tLinear Iterations\tMax Resid Norm\tWorst Node\tX\tY\tZ\tInc Max Norm\tWorst Node\tX\tY\tZ\tNodes After Adaption"
```

If you needed to use regex and you wanted to find the first line in the original file that started with the characters, "Physics", then instead of 1471 you could have used :

```
grep("^Physics", dat)-1  # gives 1471 when tested
```

I didn't think that was terribly wasteful of resources since the original file had 10 times that many lines and you end up keeping the vast majority of the characters (2.4MB from original that was 2.5MB). It was not a MCVE which you might consider reading about before your next request.

I'm only going to show the creation of a dataframe from the first 100 lines of that data object. It's pretty clearly tab delimited so `read.delim` is a suitable function:

```
 inp <- read.delim( text=dat[1:100] )
 str(inp)
  #------------------------

'data.frame':   99 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ Physics             : chr  "HYD_1" "HYD_1" "HYD_1" "TRN_1" ...
 $ Time                : num  11908800 11908800 11908800 11908800 11908800 ...
 $ dt                  : num  5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ Progress            : chr  "%0.00" "%0.00" "%0.00" "%0.00" ...
 $ Nonlinear.Iteration : int  1 2 3 1 1 1 2 3 1 1 ...
 $ Linear.Iterations   : int  6 5 5 3 0 5 4 3 3 0 ...
 $ Max.Resid.Norm      : num  5.27e+02 4.07 3.34e-04 1.47e-06 0.00 ...
 $ Worst.Node          : int  9905 9630 9630 9629 2 64661 -2 -2 1985 2 ...
 $ X                   : num  221173 221176 221176 221208 222828 ...
 $ Y                   : num  1375372 1375357 1375357 1375379 1374509 ...
 $ Z                   : num  96 96.2 96.2 96.4 100.1 ...
 $ Inc.Max.Norm        : num  0.95341 0.12883 0.001124 0.000261 0 ...
 $ Worst.Node.1        : int  9630 9630 9082 65805 452 -2 -2 -2 -2 355 ...
 $ X.1                 : num  221176 221176 221184 243925 222639 ...
 $ Y.1                 : num  1375357 1375357 1375327 1367003 1374316 ...
 $ Z.1                 : num  96.2 96.2 96.9 100.9 103.7 ...
 $ Nodes.After.Adaption: int  65926 65926 65926 65926 65926 69414 69414 69414 69414 69414 ...
```

I suggest you read the help page for the `read.*` functions: `?read.table`.
They differ in their default parameters. `read.delim` is useful for American `.tsv` files, while `read.delim2` is used for `.tsv` files that have commas as decimal separators, typically European financial reports in my experience. (I'm not sure on which side of that divide the British fall.)

You might have been able to do this in one pass if you already know the lines to skip since the `read.*` functions have skip parameters that you could specify.

Comment: IRTFM, thank you much. You are awesome!!! I have written the following code according to your direction. Cool!

Comment: Hi IRTFM, would you please let me know how to approach this problem? link is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67638639/extracting-multiple-dataframes-from-textfile-using-pattern-and-expression-in-r-p

Answer (score 1):

Thanks IRTFM,this is the code I wrote as you have directed.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(data.table)
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
dat <- readLines("D:/Shuvashish/R_adh/AR_20base_201214_adh.out" )
a=grep("^Physics", dat)-1
b=grep("^100% COMPLETE", dat)-1
dat <- dat[-(1:a)]
data <- read.delim( text=dat[1:(b-a)] )
dtm <- as.POSIXct("2017/01/01", "GMT") # Julian date start
data$t=data$Time+dtm # ADh Time was in seconds now will tun into datetime
str(data)
tail(data)
p1=ggplot(data, aes(t,dt))+geom_line()+
  scale_x_datetime( breaks = date_breaks("1 days"),labels = date_format("%m/%d/%y", tz="GMT"), 
                    expand = c(0,0))+labs(title="Time vs dt",
                                          x ="Date(mm/dd/yy)", y = "dt")+theme_classic()

p1
p2=plot(data$t, data$Nodes.After.Adaption, type = "l", col = "blue", ylab = "Nodes after adaption",xlab = "Time")+
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m-%d-%Y"))
p2


# sort top 50 worst nodes for Max Resd Normal
n1= names(sort(summary(as.factor(data$Worst.Node), decreasing=T)))[1:50]
#sort(table(data$Worst.Node),decreasing=T)
# sort top 50 worst nodes for Inc Max Norm
n2= names(sort(summary(as.factor(data$Worst.Node.1), decreasing=T)))[1:50]
n3=data.frame(n1,n2)
data_frame <- setNames(n3, c("Worst Node Max Resid","Worst Node Inc Max"))
# write.table(data_frame,"D:/Shuvashish/R_adh/myvector.txt",sep="\t",row.names=F,col.names=T)
capture.output(print(data_frame, print.gap=3,row.names = FALSE,col.names=T), file="D:/Shuvashish/R_adh/Top50Worst_nodes.txt")
```

Comment: Looks like you have sensibly used my 'greppish' advice.